# Replacement of some equal elements of a string using different values in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I want to replace each 'COL' word in the column 'b' of the 'test' data frame, by each element in the column 'a', and put the result in other column, but preserving both order and structure of the character string of the column 'b'.

```
test <- data.frame(a = c("COL167", "COL2010;COL2012"),
                   b = c("COL;MO, K", "P;COL, NY, S, COL"))
```

I have tried the following, but it is not the result that I need:

```
for(i in 1:length(test$a)){
    test$c[i] <- gsub(pattern = "COL", x = test$b[i], replacement = test$a[i])
}

> test
                a                  b                                          c
1          COL167          COL;MO, K                               COL167;MO, K
2 COL2010;COL2012  P;COL, NY, S, COL  P;COL2010;COL2012, NY, S, COL2010;COL2012
```

I expect the following result:

```
              a                  b                          c
1          COL167          COL;MO, K               COL167;MO, K
2 COL2010;COL2012  P;COL, NY, S, COL  P;COL2010, NY, S, COL2012
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what you have already done, I think this would work, but note that you might see some performance issues if your table is large. Also note that, this assumes that size of values to be replaced is equal to values used for replacement.

As `gsub` doesn't allow for vectorized replacement (replaces all the matched instances with first values of replacement), here I have converted both strings and replacements into vectors, so I can replace each matched substring individually.

```r
test <- data.frame(a = c("COL167", "COL2010;COL2012"),
                   b = c("COL;MO, K", "P;COL, NY, S, COL"))

re = function(string, replacement){
  gsub('COL', replacement, string)
}

for(i in 1:nrow(test)){
  #splitting values of column a into vector, this is required for replacement
  replacement = unlist(strsplit(test$a[i], ';'))
  
  #split values of column b into vecto, this is required for replacement
  b_value = unlist(strsplit(test$b[i], ' '))
  
  #select those which have 'COL' substring
  ind_to_replace = which(grepl('COL', b_value))
  
  #replace matched values
  result = mapply(re, b_value[ind_to_replace], replacement)
  
  #replace the column b value with new string
  b_value[ind_to_replace] = result
  
  #join the string
  test$results[i] = paste(b_value, collapse = ' ')
}

test
#>                 a                 b                   results
#> 1          COL167         COL;MO, K              COL167;MO, K
#> 2 COL2010;COL2012 P;COL, NY, S, COL P;COL2010, NY, S, COL2012
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! It was fine for a data frame with 1550 rows

Answer (score 0):

I'll propose a solution using the `rowwise` function of `dplyr`.

While it's true that `gsub` isn't vectorized, the `mgsub` function in the package of the same name is. My approach is for each row:

1. turn all of the instances of COL in column b into a vector
2. make a vector from all the COL+ entries from column a
3. use vector 2 to replace the old values of COL from b. `mutate` creates a new column with the result.

   ```
    library(mgsub)        
    library(stringr)
    library(dplyr)

    test %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(new_col = 
        unlist((mgsub(b,
              unlist(str_extract_all(b,"COL")),
              unlist(str_extract_all(a,"COL.*?\\b")))
     )))

     # A tibble: 2 x 3
     # Rowwise: 
        a               b                 new_col                  
      <chr>           <chr>             <chr>                    
   1 COL167          COL;MO, K         COL167;MO, K             
   2 COL2010;COL2012 P;COL, NY, S, COL P;COL2010, NY, S, COL2010
   ```

`mgsub` takes 3 arguments. The string you're working on, the expression you want to replace within that string, and the expression you want to use as the replacement. This package allows you to have multiple patterns to replace and be replaced - both can appear as vectors.

I applied this function to each row - first I designated the b column  as the string of interest. Second, all the `COL`'s in column b is what we want to replace and I made this into a vector using `stringr::str_extract_all`. I extracted all instances of `COL` and then we have to unlist this output because  `str_extract_all` returns a list. Third, I used the same process to extract the `COL+` entries from column a. In summary, we use the entries in column a to replace the characters of interest within column b.

```
    "COL.*?\\b"
```

selects the letters `COL` followed by as few characters as possible before reaching a word boundary which allows us to turn the entries in column a into multiple items (COL2010, COL2012 etc).

We have to unlist the mutated row (i.e. the first "unlist") because `dplyr` outputs a list-column.